# How to fix problem: HTML with template can be opened in preview mode, but the template is not visible while running the application

Tags: html

It's the first time I'm using an HTML design template from the internet. So, the problem is that my HTML page looks correct when I open it from the IntelliJ chrome button, but when I run the whole application, I only see a "nude" page. I suppose the problem is the usage of "th:" but I cannot understand where I need to put them.

[html page when opened from chrome button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5dUz.png)

[html page when the app is being ran](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Kqff.png)

My html code of this page:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <!-- Basic -->
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <!-- Mobile Metas -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <!-- Site Metas -->
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="" />
    <title>Bob in Wonderland</title>


    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/signin/signin.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- bootstrap core css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}" />
        <!-- fonts style -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700|Poppins:400,600,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <!-- responsive style -->
        <link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    </html>
<body class="sub_page">
<div class="hero_area">

    <header class="header_section">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg custom_nav-container ">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                    <h3>
                        Bob
                    </h3>
                    <span> in Wonderland</span>
                    <span> Library Management System </span>
                </a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
    </header>
                </a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section class="login_section layout_padding">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="detail-box">
                        <h3>
                            Welcome to the book paradise
                        </h3>
                        <p>
                            Log into your account now and get unlimited access to hundreds of our
                            online books
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="login_form">
            <h5>
                Login Now
            </h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-error">Wrong user or password</p>
    <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
        <label for="username">Username</label>:
        <input type="text" id="username" name="email" autofocus="autofocus" /> <br />
        <label for="password">Password</label>:
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" /> <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
    </form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like an issue related to specifically your file structure, and it is most likely caused by the following not being able to load:

```
        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <!-- responsive style -->
        <link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

More information can be found in the Network column of the chrome dev tools navbar. To access chrome dev tools, simply left click and hit 'inspect'. Then navigate over to the Network tab and then reload the page. You will be able to see all of the outgoing requests your browser is making, and you will be able to see exactly which files are not being loaded and get a general idea as to why. Here are some error codes that may be useful:

```
200 - O.K.
403 - Forbidden from accessing resource (Permission Issue)
404 - File not found 
5xx - Internal server errors
```